# argparse: make subparsers depend on a previous argument

Tags: python, argparse

My program receives arguments (yes, original concept here), the 1st one being a "type". I would like to add an argument, "foo", only if this "type" is set to a certain value. Can I use subparsers for that, or anything else?

Here is an extract of what I would do:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-t', '--type', nargs=1, type=str, required=True)
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers()

# HERE: if parent subparser's type == 'a', allow use of argument "foo"
# else it is forbidden
parser_a = subparsers.add_parser(...)
parser_a.add_argument('-foo', help='bar help')
```

Comment: What is the *problem* with what you've written? If `type` is a sub-command, then only add the `foo` argument to that sub-parser.

Comment: @jonsharpe That's the answer: `type` needs to be a subcommand, not an option on the main parser.

Comment: first --f second --foo... https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#conflict-handler

Comment: Thanks! Ok, that's what I was beginning to see... and dont' want! "type" is not a subcommand, so I will have to add checks later on and throw errors with `parser.error`. Ugly, but I'll do that.

Comment: @SDilmac: I'm sorry but I don't understand your point... In what could that help me fix my case?

Comment: There's nothing wrong or ugly about doing your own checks after `argparse`.  Forcing the parser to perform those checks often requires more complicated code (e.g. custom Action class).

Comment: How would you explain to your users (or yourself 6 mths from now) this conditional requirement?